# Where is the nano file located?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, nano

I'm using FileZilla and have found the default **LibreOffice Writer** not the best for on-the-go code editing.

I have the option to **use custom program** for text editing, so why not give nano a go. So I'm wondering, where is the nano (shell script?) file located?

I had a quick Google for this question and only found an ArchLinux forum posing the question on [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=49562).

From the thread, I checked `/usr/bin/nano` and it's not existant there.

Comment: FWIW, depending on the features you might need, vim and emacs are both very powerful, bit of a learning curve to them. Gedit also has a number of nice plugins - https://www.linux.com/learn/vim-101-beginners-guide-vim and https://www.maketecheasier.com/transform-gedit-into-a-web-developer-ide/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest method:

```
$ which nano
/bin/nano
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use

```
$ whereis nano
nano: /bin/nano
```

Answer (score 0):

You might like `geany` which is a useful GUI editor for text files.

```
sudo apt-get install geany
```

Comment: Installed it, very nice :) I'll stick to Nano for quick edits though.

Comment: That is a good idea, @Jek. For example, I use nano to edit (small) system files and configuration files which need elevated permissions, for example `sudo nano /etc/fstab` otherwise I use `geany` most of the time.

Comment: I'm in the same area @sudodus, I use nano for small things BUT I use atom for project development and larger files. I have a serious love for nano being able to go to a specific line, I don't know why. `nano ./httpf.conf +250`

Comment: This answer is better suited as a comment.